# How to use GraphQL in .net framework with ADO.NET

Tags: .net, graphql, ado.net

I can see a lot of articles about using GraphQL in .net core with Entity Framework. But I want to use GraphQL with ADO.NET. Is there any way to connect the GraphQL resolver to the ADO.NET?